# Syntax Error: missing ; before statement [JSONP, Instagram API]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, instagram-api

I'm trying to fetch json response from Instragram API with no result.

I use the code below which fetch data, but with error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "Get",
            url :"https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?access_token=MYTOKEN&lat=00.0&lng=00.0&distance=30000?callback=?",
            dataType :"jsonp",
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: " ",
            success : function(instagramres){
                alert(instagramres);
                document.write(instagramres.meta.code);
            },
            error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
                alert(status+" "+exception);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have changed `jsonp:false` to `jsonp:true` with no result.

My screenshot through chrome dev console:
[image: Chrome Dev Console output]

Comment: at what point does the error gets thrown?

Comment: Remove `jsonp: false`, `jsonpCallback: " "` and change `Get` to `get`. You would be better off using the ajax shorthand for JSON -> [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: at `jsonpCallback: " testcallback",` i'm getting `parsererror: Error testcallback was not called`.

If i remove this line i'm getting `parsererror Error: jQuery181011872481792222633_1438084410647 was not called`

Comment: @lshettyl if i remove `jsonp: false`, `jsonpCallback` and change `get`, i'm getting `parsererror Error: jQuery18107422583257549523_1438084470015 was not called`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you don't need params such as `type` (as by default it's `get`) and `jsonpCallback` (unless you want to have your own callback method). You may specify the callback thru the `jsonp` param. Take a look at the code below and see if that works for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?access_token=MYTOKEN&lat=00.0&lng=00.0&distance=30000",
        // The name of the callback parameter
        jsonp: "callback",
        // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",
        // Deal with the response
        success: function(instagramres){
            alert(instagramres);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You 're right!! `Type: "get"` and `jsonp: "false"` create the problem. Now i fix it.

Thanks @lshettyl